# Qtcreator when make is done error #include <QGLViewer/qglviewer.h> No file or folder of this type

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, qt-creator

I installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS yesterday and i'm trying to run an exemple on QtCreator.
When i do *qmake* in the file he generates the makefile, but when i do *make* this error happens :

(Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type -> No file or folder of this type)

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtXml -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o simpleViewer.o simpleViewer.cpp
In file included from simpleViewer.cpp:23:0:
simpleViewer.h:23:10: fatal error: QGLViewer/qglviewer.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include <QGLViewer/qglviewer.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:364: recipe for target 'simpleViewer.o' failed
make: *** [simpleViewer.o] Error 1
```

Did i miss somethings when i installed Qtcreator ? I don't know where qglviewer.h is supposed to be... I'm new with QtCreator.
(Sorry for my english)

Comment: `packages.ubuntu.com` says this file is in the `libqglviewer-headers` package. You probably want the `libqglviewer-dev-qt5` package as well for the actual library.

Comment: @Botje Thank you so much !!!! It works perfectly, you are my savior ;)